# matlap GMM of multivariate distibutions

Tags: matlab, distribution

I am a newbie in Matlab, so sorry for a stupid question.

I want to create a sequence of 2-dimensional vectors generated from GMM that consist of three multivariate normal distributions.

so, let's start

```
 mu = [[0 1]; [0 2]; [0 3]]
 cov = cat(4, 0, 0.5)
 p = [0.4 0.4 0.2]
 obj = gmdistribution(mu, cov, p)
```

The problem is this sequence of commands doesn't work.

In addition, I want these three distribution to have a small overlap. I don't know how to evaluate mu and cov such that they will have a small overlap.

Comment: What do you want the three covariance matrices to be?

Comment: @hbaderts, it doesn't matter, at the first place I want the whole idea to be working, at the second place I want all three distribution to have a small overlap

Comment: Are you sure you are using cat the way you want to use it? I don't see why you would want a 4-D double...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `cov` is the name of the covariance function, so you better call your variable e.g. `sigma`. Second, you create the `cov` variable to be a 4-D array with value `0` at `cov(1,1,1,1)` and `0.5` at `cov(1,1,1,2)`.

Depending on how the covariance matrices looks, the variable `sigma` can look different. Let `d` be the number of dimensions (2 in your example), and `k` be the number of distributions (3 in your example).

**General case:**
Each of the Gaussian distributions has an arbitrary covariance matrix. `sigma` is of size `d`x`d`x`n`, i.e. 2x2x3, where `sigma(:,:,k)` is the `k`th covariance matrix. Note that of course the covariance matrices have to be symmetric and positive semidefinite. You do that e.g. by

```
sigma(:,:,1) = [1.0, 0.5 ; 0.5, 2.0];
sigma(:,:,2) = [0.8, 0.1 ; 0.1, 0.2];
sigma(:,:,3) = [1.2, 0.4 ; 0.4, 0.3];
```

**Diagonal covariance matrices** If all your covariance matrices are diagonal, you can specify sigma as a `1`x`d`x`k`(1x2x3) matrix, where `sigma(1,:,k)` are the diagonal elements of the `k`th covariance matrix. E.g.

```
sigma(1,:,1) = [1.0, 2.0];
sigma(1,:,2) = [0.8, 0.2];
sigma(1,:,3) = [1.2, 0.3];
```

**Identical covariance matrices** If all `k` covariance matrices are identical, it is enough if you specify it once

```
sigma = [1.0, 0.5 ; 0.5, 2.0];
```

**Identical, diagonal covariance matrices** If all `k` covariance matrices are identical diagonal matrices, `sigma` is a vector containing the diagonal elements

```
sigma = [1.0, 2.0];
```